# Google Apps Script - Date prints different to sheet than on apps editor

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, datetime-format

As we know, using TODAY() function in sheets updates to the current date every time the doc is opened. I need the date to stay constant once it is added.

So, I wrote a little code to be able to print today's date in google sheets.

```
function todaysDate() {
  var td = new Date();
  m = td.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' })
  return (td.getDate() + " " + m ) + " " + td.getFullYear();
}

console.log(todaysDate());
```

This code results in **9 Mar 2023**. [Pic: Code + Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXht5.png)

However, the date prints correct in the GAS Project Editor on console.log, however, when added to the sheet, the result is wrong.

This is what appears in sheets **9 M03 2023**. [Pic: Outcome in Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4be49.png)

Appreciate any ideas on how to resolve this. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get into some problems with `toLocaleString()` you can try to set a specific formatting of the date using `Intl.DateTimeFormat` this code hopefully formats it correctly in sheets also.

```
function todaysDate() {
  var td = new Date();
  var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { month: 'short' });
  var month = formatter.format(td);
  return (td.getDate() + " " + month ) + " " + td.getFullYear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Clear and simple way of getting the month short name. It works, I've tested it.

```
function todaysDate() {
  var td = new Date();
  var monthShortNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
  ];
  var m = monthShortNames[td.getMonth()];
  return (td.getDate() + " " + m) + " " + td.getFullYear();
}
```